Finding the volume of the nonnegative solution space of Ax=b
I'm working on a problem where I've got $Ax = b$ where $A$ is a tall rectangular matrix (on the order of $3 \times 30$) with only non-negative entries and $x$ and $b$ are known to be non-negative vectors by the nature of the problem. Given that, I'm interested not in finding specific solutions to $Ax=b$ as was done here, but actually in finding the volume of the nonnegative solution space for different values of $b$.
How would you approach this problem and is it tractable? I'd love for an analytic solution if possible, but I suppose an approximation would work for me too, as I really just need the relative volumes of the solution space for different $b$ rather than the absolute value.

This might be a place to start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Obtaining_all_solutions_of_a_linear_system

@EricTowers Yeah I was thinking along those lines, where we could start from some known solution ($A^+b$) and then traverse along the null space to find other solutions. My fear though is that by adding the constraint that $x$ must be nonnegative, it is hard to efficiently find the specific vertices and volume of the polyhedra that encompasses all the nonnegative solutions. Each vertex would have at least one entry of zero, and I suppose there are up to $2^N$ vertices, so that kinda seems like a computationally expensive approach.

I see two phases: is the solution set empty (can be addressed by the startup stage of linear programming), if not, the solution set is finite (can't be parallel to the boundary of the first orthant) and is the intersection of an affine subspace and the first orthant, so you only need the solution spans on the 1-dimensional boundaries of the orthant (the coordinate axes) -- every other solution is a weighted sum of these on-axis solutions.
